# Filter array based on other entries in same array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting, duplicates

I've got an array with items, each item has a `duration` and a `price`.

I want to filter out the duplicate `duration` values based on the `price` value - keeping the lowest.

Array:

```
$arr = [
  [
    'duration' => 60, // this item should be filtered
    'price' => 100
  ],
  [
    'duration' => 120,
    'price' => 190
  ],
  [
    'duration' => 60, // this one should remain in array
    'price' => 75
  ]
]
```

I'm using Laravel as a framework, so I'm able to use the collection-methods.

So I now achieve this as follows:

```
$arr->sortByDesc('price')
  ->keyBy('duration') // duplicate entries are overwritten 
                      // with the latest/lowest value
  ->sortBy('price');
```

But this feels a little bit sketchy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
$collection = collect($arr);
$filtered = $collection->sortBy('duration')->sortBy('price')->unique('duration');
```

It should works also as

```
$collection = collect($arr);
$filtered = $collection->sortBy('price')->unique('duration');
```

Comment: I don't use Laravel, but based on what I read in the manual, Simone's second method seems to be the best `collection` approach.  It sorts ASC and unique() keeps the first occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
$arr = [
  [
    'duration' => 60, // this item should be filtered
    'price' => 100
  ],
  [
    'duration' => 120,
    'price' => 190
  ],
  [
    'duration' => 60, // this one should remain in array
    'price' => 75
  ]
];

rsort($arr);   // sort the subarrays by duration DESC
// assign keys to each subarray using duration value
$arr=array_values(array_combine(array_column($arr,'duration'),$arr));
// this overwrites more expensive subarrays with less expensive subarrays
var_export($arr);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'duration' => 120,
    'price' => 190,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'duration' => 60,
    'price' => 75,
  ),
)
```